# Running a dockerized application on Kubernetes cluster using helm chart

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-helm

I have an application already running on a docker container. The goal is to have it run on a kubernetes cluster (minikube) using helm charts

For this, I have already setup minikube as the cluster, installed kubectl and helm and have it running. How do I run my docker application on the kubernetes cluster? Is there any good guide out there I could follow for the same as a starting point? Unfortunately, I was unable to figure this out in spite of lots of effort on searching for it.

Comment: You should probably start here and work your way up: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is:

- write a helm chart
- run helm commands to install that chart

It would be better if you know about helm and it's stuffs. The official doc https://docs.helm.sh/ for helm is best.

But for your needs, you will find what will have to be done by going through [Packaged Kubernetes Deployments – Writing a Helm Chart](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/packaged-kubernetes-deployments-writing-helm-chart/). It is just similar what you need.

Happy Helming!

Comment: At the moment I am creating the kubernetes deployment files (yaml) . Converting it to helm would mean to have the different kubernetes resources \ yaml files mapped as one chart so that it could be created together (helm install) , Although it could be much more, is that the basic idea?